# jquery / html add class on radio button check, else remove class if radio button not checked?

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, with the same name group 'select'

HTML:

```
<div class="select_box_outer">
<span class="select_box">
<input type="radio" id="select" name="select" value="same">
<div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
<div class="checkbox_tick2"></div>
</span>
</div>


<div class="select_box_outer">
<span class="select_box">
<input type="radio" id="select" name="select" value="same">
<div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
<div class="checkbox_tick2"></div>
</span>
</div>
```

The options here are 'Yes' or 'No'

if a user checks one of the radio buttons then I want the parent div 'select_box_outer' to have a class added 'select_box_outer2' which basically changes the css of my div background colour the border and adds a shadow to the div 'select_box_outer'.

Then if the radio button is de-checked then it should remove the class and go back to the original css settings for 'select_box_outer'.

I also have 'checkbox_tick' displayed when a radio button is not checked, this appears as a greyed out tick. But If the radio button is checked then 'checkbox_tick' css should be display none and my div 'checkbox_tick2' should be displayed as block. But if the radio button is then de-checked then it should switch back to 'checkbox_tick'.

I am struggling to get to grips with what I would need to do here, please can someone show me where I am going wrong? Thanks in advance:

JQUERY:

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("input[name=select]").change(function(){          


            if ($(this).val() === "Yes") {
            $(this).parents('div.select_box_outer').addClass( "select_box_outer2" );
$('div.checkbox_tick').css('display', 'none');
            }
            else {
            $(this).parents('div.select_box_outer').removeClass( "select_box_outer2" );
$('div.checkbox_tick2').css('display', 'block');
            }                                                            
       });
});
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.select_box_outer{
    width:150px;
    height:130px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-bradius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
cursosr:hand;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:50px;
}

.select_box_outer2 {
    background: #FFB631; /* Or some other color */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-moz-opacity: 1;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox_tick{
 height:55px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../images/tick.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size:35px 35px;
position:relative;
display:none;
margin:auto;

}

.checkbox_tick2{
 height:55px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../images/tick.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size:35px 35px;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}
```

Comment: WHY IS YOUR TITLE SHOUTING AT ME??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="select_box_outer">
<span class="select_box">
<input type="radio" id="select" name="select" value="same">
<div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
<div class="checkbox_tick2" style="display:none;"></div>
</span>
</div>


<div class="select_box_outer">
    <span class="select_box">
        <input type="radio" id="select2" name="select" value="same">
        <div class="checkbox_tick"></div>
        <div class="checkbox_tick2" style="display:none;"></div>
    </span>
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("input[name=select]").change(function(){          

        $('.select_box_outer').removeClass("select_box_outer2");
        $('.checkbox_tick').css('display', 'block');
        $('.checkbox_tick2').css('display', 'none');

        $(this).parents('div.select_box_outer').addClass( "select_box_outer2" );
        $(this).siblings('div.checkbox_tick').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).siblings('div.checkbox_tick2').css('display', 'block');

    });
});
</script>

<style>

.select_box_outer{
    width:150px;
    height:130px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background: #eee;
    box-shadow: 1px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-bradius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor:pointer;
cursosr:hand;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity: 0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
display:inline-block;
margin-right:50px;
}

.select_box_outer2 {
    background: #FFB631; /* Or some other color */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
-moz-opacity: 1;
-khtml-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox_tick{
 height:55px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../images/tick.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size:35px 35px;
position:relative;
display:none;
margin:auto;

}

.checkbox_tick2{
 height:55px;
width:100%;
background-image: url('../images/tick.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size:35px 35px;
position:relative;
margin:auto;
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Chrome 19+, Safari 6+, Safari 6+ iOS */
}    

</style>
```

Comment: thanks for this, this is almost bang on apart from when a user checks the radio button checkbox_tick2 is shown but if they de-check checkbox_tick2 should hide/display none and checkbox_tick should be shown.

Comment: Hello James, i have updated the jquery script code. Its working fine now. Please try it. and lets reply me.

Answer (score 0):

why not use something like this?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input.check").click(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parent().addClass("selectedclass");
        }
    });
});
```

just add an if and else statement and you should get what you need

Comment: but I'm using radio buttons not checkbox? does this matter? or does it do the same thing whether checkbox or radio button? also where abouts between the tags would I add my else statement? sorry to ask but am really new to jquery

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I tried this but it's not doing anything?

Comment: thanks for the example but that is not quite what I want. I need something that will simply add a class (i.e. change the background colour of a div) and then reset the div to the original background colour when it is not checked